# Write record in linear fixed structure by using APDU Command

Tags: smartcard, apdu, scosta

I have successfully created Linear fixed file structure EF file in SCOSTA smart card BY USING following APDU Command

> `00 E0 00 00 1B 62 19 82 05 03 41 00 25 05 83 02 60 01 8A 01 01 88 01 48 8C 06 6E FF FF 22 25 25`

I am also try to write the record oriented file using this APDU command.

> `00 DC 00 04 12 (Data=41 73 70 65 72 67 69 6C 6C 69 75 73 3A 6E 6E 6E 6E 6E)`

But I got the error (6A85) LC inconsistent with TLV structure. I need the solution to write the smart card EF record oriented file. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to send an *UPDATE RECORD* command directly after creation. At this time no record may be available yet (some operating systems initialize a file with empty records, but this is no ISO-requirement).

- First proposal is, to use *Append Record* instead
- If this fails, verify that the record size of the created file matches your data. I can't find any *12* in the file control information, so there may be a mismatch. If I read the SCOSTA specification correctly, the record size specified is 0x25. In that case you MUST pad the data yourself, to achieve the correct record size.